# Frequency polygon area

Tags: descriptive-statistics, histogram

If I have a histogram with bins equal width, then the area of the histogram is the same as the area of the frequency polygon.

What about if we have an histogram with bins of different width? I think the area will be different. True? why?

Comment: In principle the area under the histogram and the area under the frequency polygon should be the same. Having bins of unequal width doesn't affect that. Whether you get close will depend on the data and how crude your binning is.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for your interest and help.
In the case of equal widths, the area is always the same, irrespective of binning. I've just read that with 'variable' width, the imaginary bins' width we create will depend on each case. I was thinking if we could always adapt them, so that the polygon would have area 1.

By the way, do you know any reference to this subject? The info I find is very scarce...

Comment: I've never seen the point of frequency polygons so I have  no literature links beyond dimly recollecting that there's some discussion in http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471547700.html

Comment: Some people confuse bar plots with histograms. The difference is that histograms represent probabilities (or relative frequencies) by means of *areas* rather than lengths of bars.  Thus if you have a plot with bins of different width and its area is not unity, then by definition it is not a histogram. A good reference is [Freedman, Pisani, & Purves, *Statistics*](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0393929728/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1944687702&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0393970833&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1PJ0NSQA6924R1HN1ZWN#reader_0393929728) (any edition).

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for the link. ;) Let's assume that I have an histogram of area 1, but with different widths. What will be the area under the frequency polygon?

Comment: If you draw it correctly, the area will be the total frequency.  The usual method uses $n$ bins with frequencies $f_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ at cutpoints $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and connects their midpoints $((x_{i-1}, x_i)/2, f_i/(x_i-x_{i-1})),i=1,2, \ldots,n$ with a polyline. The area under that line is too small. The correct method adjoins two more points at $((3x_0-x_1)/2,0)$ and $((3x_n-x_{n-1})/2,0)$, creating two small triangles at the ends: now the total area is the total frequency.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Could you write an answer, with a bit more elaboration, please? It would help me a lot. ;)